# Error java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: hibernate

al hacer run en mi programa me marca este error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
tengo agregada la libreria EclipseLink y Persistencia, pero no puedo eliminar este error.

Comment: Hola Juan bienvenido, podrías editar tu pregunta , y agregar como texto, el código completo del mensaje de error?, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.